# How to show if ParseUser is online?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have implemented Parse in android app.Now suppose there are two users in my app A and B.Now if B is online I am trying to maintain a boolean variable isOnline to check the status of the user.Now B is able to continuosly check this variable whether user is online.But I am trying to set isOnline false as soon as B is not able to connect.But the problem is arising that if B is not able to connect and network is disconnected then I can not set this variable to false.What is the exact way to implement this.
It is the scenario like in whatsApp.Please help me.

Comment: Dear Rahul, To implement the scenario above, you may have your own server. When a user log in to system you can send a notification to your server. On the other hand when your user is logged out you can send log out notification. Using socket communication can help. (if internet is gone then socket is closed).  This  first comes my mind. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement by only using Parse, however I would **not** recommend this, as it it quite inefficient and will use up your API calls quite quickly.

For this example, assume a refresh rate of 30 seconds.

When a user (User **A**) is connected (so say, the app is open), then every 30 seconds, you can set some field: object.set("lastOnline",currentTime).

If the user drops offline, their "lastOnline" value will stop being updated.

User **B** also polls for the User **A** object, and queries the *lastOnline* field. So say 
   user = user.get(); 
   lastOnline = user.get("lastOnline") 
   if(time.now - lastOnline > 30 seconds ){
     user is offline 
   } else {
     user is online
   }

I wouldn't recommend this technique, as user **A** is pushing an update every 30 seconds, and user **B** is pulling down a new object every 30 seconds. So that is 240 API calls per hour for only 2 users.

You might be better off using a platform like PubNub, in conjunction with Parse. With PubNub handling chat type functionality, and Parse handling more general data storage.

Comment: Wow.Its a great idea PubNub in conjunction with parse! :)
But I dont know even 1% of PubNub.Any shortcut to learn it quickly??

Comment: I would start with their tutorials: http://www.pubnub.com/developers/tutorials/publish-subscribe/ Your goal though (building an app with multiple users, real time online connectivity status etc), is certainly not a simple app, so unfortunately nothing is going to be too quick. There are client side, as well as a lot of server side considerations. 

If you are trying to do something such as add chat functionality to an app, I'd probably start with a nice library such as: https://layer.com

Comment: Okay thanks a lot no other option for me right now.So I will try to do it with pubhub

Comment: Ok, note that PubNub doesn't actually have any built in "Show me if a user is online" feature, it is simply another hosted framework which allows for peer-to-peer comms. I imagine it might be slightly more appropriate for your needs though.